# Ubuntu crashes when run out of RAM

Tags: freeze, ram, crash

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a DELL server with 128GB of RAM

When RAM usage reaches 100%, the system freezes immediately. I can move the coursor for a couple of seconds and then have to reboot the system.
Swap file (8GB) usage according to `htop` preservers zero.

What else can be the reason of the crashing?

Comment: If the system runs out of RAM, and swap is not used, then there must be an issue with your swap storage, or perhaps you changed settings like `swapiness`. Provide more information on your system configuration: use "edit".

Comment: There is insufficient information to offer an answer here. What sort of tasks is the server performing? Have you confirmed swappiness is cromulent? Is there I/O contention?

Comment: Easiest solution, either deactivate swap file or use a swap partition.

Reason for your problem: Your swap file is probably located on a qcow-like-filesystem like _btrfs_. Make sure your swap file is not a sparse file and make sure your swap file is not fragmented. Better, just use a real swap partition.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1349127/edit) to explain: Where is your `free` or `htop` output to show that swap is not being used? How long are you waiting before powering off? (sluggish behavior due to swapping will pass when swap is no longer needed)  Where is your troubleshooting to verify that swap is detected by the system, and turned on? Why is your available Swap so small? Where are your log entries to demonstrate that swap is the culprit instead of a crashing program?

Comment: I agree with previous comments. Also, and as a test, try increasing minimum free kilobytes. Do: `echo "20000000" | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes` to increase it to 20 gigabytes, for example, and what I would suggest to start with.